# Como puedo guardar cualquier string en un archico csv?

Tags: css, c

necesito guardar esto en una celda de un archivo .csv

```
printf(" %05d   ", offset);
```

en el print de arriba me muestra datos numericos, esos numeros quiero guardarlos

actualmente estoy guardando asi:

```
strcpy(last->packet, offset);
```

pero cuando veo el guardado, veo caracteres raros: por ejemplo: ��yU

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo es copiar el *entero* que tenga guardado `offset` en `packet`, ahí está mal, el segundo parámetro de la función `strcpy` es de tipo `char*` y le estás pasando un `int`. Una posible solución es convertir el entero en *string* con la función [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). De igual manera, sería bueno que incluyas en la pregunta de que tamaño es el buffer `packet`, ya que debe coincidir con el buffer de destino, de lo contrario, habrá desborde.